# Is there a better way to get 5 most significant digits on vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

The better way to get 5 most significant digits on vb.net?

```
         436523423900000->43652 
         .0000000034543853658400003763746 -> 34543
```

**This is my current code**:-

```
Public Function priceSignficant() As Double
    Dim lnPrice = Math.Log10(_price)
    Dim floorLnPrice = Math.Floor( lnPrice )
    Dim significantprice = 10 ^ floorLnPrice


    Return significantprice
End Function
Public Function priceSignificantDigit() As ULong
    Dim pricesig = priceSignficant()
    Dim ratio = _price / pricesig
    Dim i = 0
    Do
        Dim closeenough = ratio - Math.Round(ratio)
        Dim closeneough1 = Math.Abs(closeenough)
        If closeneough1 > 0.000000001 Then
            ratio *= 10
            i += 1
            If i > 5 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Return CULng(ratio)
End Function
```

It's sort of work.

There has to be easier way.

Answer (score 2):

For positive numbers, you can calculate the number of digits with `Log10` and then simply shift the number by this amount (subtract 5) using a division:

```
Dim numberOfDigits = Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(number))
Dim significantDigits = Math.Truncate(number * Math.Pow(10, 5 - numberOfDigits))
```

If you have negative numbers, calculate the absolute value with `Math.Abs` and continue as above.